# Specifying the IP address + SNI with SSLContext

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

How can one specify the IP address of the server you wish to connect to *along with* the SNI using Python's SSLContext?

I can specify the SNI alone easily, but haven't been able to determine how to point the request a specific IP address

E.g This will result in 'mywebsite' being sent within the 'Client Hello'

```
 hostname = "mywebsite"
 context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)
```

How do you control the IP you connect to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How was your `sock` variable created?

It is a socket, hence it is where the destination IP and ports are specified, before calling `wrap_socket`.

Like:

```
sock = socket.create_connection((HOST, PORT))
```

At the TLS level it is "too late": TLS handshake happens after the TCP/IP connection is established, so at the time you send the SNI extension, you are already connected to a specific IP address (and port).

Comment: Thank you. Was having issues combining the socket with SSLContexts, but it seems to work if you RTFM!